# What exactly do skill upgrades do?

Tags: pokken-tournament

From doing the tutorials in Pokken Tournament, overall I was pretty impressed with how well-done it was as an actual fighting game and not just shoving Pokemon somewhere they don't belong.

However, the description of skill points at levelups was a little concerning. How much do skill points actually affect your stats in battle? When you play online, are your skill upgrades taken into account? Does it actually give an advantage (however slight) to the person who has played longer and accrued more levels with their character?

Answer (score 1):

The skill point upgrades boost the skill you assign them to. The level ups allow you Pokémon to be stronger stat-wise. The Synergy Burst one boosts the power of the Synergy attack, etc. I actually played this game a lot, so I know more about the topic. Also, you may actually win against someone be experienced, but the chances are very slim.